# Search service installation on existing CF 11

Tags: solr, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfadmin

We have ColdFusion 11 installed and working on production Windows Server 2012 R2 server. Search Services and Solr were not initially installed. What would be the steps to add them now?  Is there a simple way to do it on a running system?

Your input and advice are appreciated!

Comment: Might be better to ask over on https://serverfault.com as this isn't a code-related question.

Answer (score 0):

Try installation from ColdFusion 11 developer tools as a fresh install for SOLR. I found this link below. Give it a shot and let us know if you have any issues.

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/coldfusion/updates/11/addonservices/ColdFusion_11_Addon_win.exe